# QGIS PostgreSQL connection working but very slow on mobile connection

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I'm working with a QGIS project while commuting with train, it works rather alright. The problem is that rendering a PostgreSQL table on my mobile connection takes very long time compared when I'm on my home wifi. (I have a PostgreSQL server at home that I store data in)

I usually have a rather fast mobile connection (50Mbit/s down and 5Mbit/s upp) but I guess that I have a rather high loss. Is there any setting or something I can do to improve the rendering speed?

Comment: This seems less like a GIS question than a pure IT one.

Comment: Well I have no issues working with the data in pgadmin or with python - psycopg2, where would you suggest that I ask the "pure IT" question?